# Loading content of webview javafx using a different thread

Tags: java, javafx

I have created an application that uses a thread in background and  created a webview in foreground.
And a function:

```
public void reloadWebview(){
      webView.getEngine().loadContent(something);
}
```

And I called this function using thread I have created  on background.

But it is showing a error like...
Not a Javafx application thread something..

Hope you have solition for this problem.

Comment: `loadContent()` is already asynchronous: [ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent-java.lang.String-). So to trigger the load from a different thread, just wrap the `loadContent()` call in `Platform.runLater()` - it will not block the UI.

Comment: Ya I used it. But using it blocks my all window components and my app gets completely strucked.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do all the background work inside `Platform.runLater(..)` instead of just wrapping the call to `loadContent()` in it.